# Show that the expectation value of the position with a Harmonic oscillator is $\langle x \rangle_{\psi(t)} = A\cos(\omega t + \phi)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

I am working on a harmonic oscillator problem I have not seen before. Given the position operator 
$$\hat{x} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}(a^{\dagger}+a)$$
and 
$$|{\psi}\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_{n}|{n}\rangle$$ 
where $\alpha_{n}$ are complex coefficients normalized such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\alpha_{n}|^{2}=1$. The question is to calculate the expected value of $\hat{x}$ in the general time-dependent state $|{\psi(t)}\rangle$ and show that it is on the form 
$$\langle x \rangle_{\psi(t)} = A\cos(\omega t + \phi)$$
where $\psi$ and $A$ are expressed in therms of $\alpha_{n}$.

I have only worked with time-independent examples, and where $\psi$ was represented as a single ket/function, so this task is new to me.

Comment: I am guessing $|n\rangle$ are the energy eigenstates?

Comment: So you have $\vert \Psi(t)\rangle=\sum_n a_n e^{-iiE_n t/\hbar}\vert n\rangle$ and continue as before with $\vert \Psi(t)\rangle$ keeping track of the time exponentials.

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes, I forgot to mention that

Comment: @ZeroTheHero How did you you get that value?

Comment: @Anonymous Just look up deriving the TISE from the TDSE. I would get a new book and new professor if you have not seen the expression given by ZeroTheHero.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Also it looks like you have an extra $i$ in there

Comment: @AaronStevens yup sorry for the typo.

Comment: @AaronStevens I get your comment now. But do you know how I can express $\omega$ and A in terms of $\alpha_{n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for simplicity
$$
\vert\Psi(t)\rangle = c_1 e^{-i E_1t/\hbar}\vert 1\rangle + 
c_2  e^{-i E_2t/\hbar}\vert 2\rangle\, .
$$
Note that, at $t=0$, this yields 
$$
\vert\Psi(0)\rangle = c_1 \vert 1\rangle + 
c_2  \vert 2\rangle\, .
$$
and since the time-dependent Schrödinger equation is a first order ODE the value of $\vert\Psi(0)\rangle$ is enough to determine the coefficients $c_n$ and so give the time evolution of the initial state 
$\vert\Psi(0)\rangle$ in terms of the evolution of the eigenstates of $\hat H$.

Then for an observable $\hat{A}$
\begin{align}
\langle A\rangle &= 
 c^*_1 c_1\langle  1\vert \hat A 
 \vert 1\rangle + 
 c^*_1 e^{i E_1t/\hbar}c_2  e^{-i E_2t/\hbar}\langle 1\vert \hat A\vert 2\rangle\\
&+ c_1 e^{-i E_1t/\hbar}c^*_2  e^{i E_2t/\hbar}\langle 2\vert \hat A\vert 1\rangle+
 c^*_2 c_2\langle  2\vert \hat A 
 \vert 2\rangle 
\end{align}
so time-dependent cross terms will in general appear unless $\langle 1\vert \hat A\vert 2\rangle =0$.

Comment: Thanks. But isn’t this just for two energy values? I also need the expectation on the form $A\cos(\omega t + \phi)$

Comment: No.   This is the general form of the evolution.  By the TDSE the states evolve like so *in general*.  The expectation value is real so it will work out to be $\cos(\omega t+\phi)$.  The $\omega$ will occur because only state $\langle n \vert \hat x\vert n\pm 1\rangle$ will contribute and these differ by one $E_n-E_{n\pm 1}=\pm \hbar \omega$, so the oscillation will be of frequency $\hbar \omega/\hbar$, i.e. $\omega$.

Comment: I've help you enough.  If you actually push through the calculation it will sort itself out.  All you need to remember is that $e^{i\omega t} Q + e^{i\omega t}Q^*$ is $\vert Q\vert e^{i(\omega t + \phi)}$ if $Q=\vert Q\vert e^{i\phi}$ for any $Q$.

Comment: Yes. You did. I get it now. Thanks for the help., the problem is that I have to show that it is real.

Comment: I have also never worked with TDSE. This is the first problem I have seen of this kind. So the conclusions you have made are not natural to me.